# submitting csv form data with jquery then showing as json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, csv

I am a beginner in jquery so this may be stupid.
I want to take csv data from the user and transform it into json. Found a nice library but don't quite understand how the submitting is done in jquery.

For instance if I have a view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('public/js/jquery.js') ?>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('javascript/main.js') ?>" ></script>


    <div id="message"><p></p></div>

    <form id="convertForm" name="convertForm" onsubmit="return false; ">
        CSV<br /><textarea id="csv" name="csv" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br /><br />

        JSON<br /><textarea id="json" name="json" rows="10" cols="60" readonly="readonly"></textarea><br /><br />


        <input type="button" value="Convert" id="submitButton"/> <input type="reset" />
    </form>
```

And the main.js file

```
function parseCSVLine (line)

            {
                line = line.split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
                {
                    var chunk = line[i].replace(/^[\s]*|[\s]*$/g, "");
                    var quote = "";
                    if (chunk.charAt(0) == '"' || chunk.charAt(0) == "'") quote = chunk.charAt(0);
                    if (quote != "" && chunk.charAt(chunk.length - 1) == quote) quote = "";

                    if (quote != "")
                    {
                        var j = i + 1;

                        if (j < line.length) chunk = line[j].replace(/^[\s]*|[\s]*$/g, "");

                        while (j < line.length && chunk.charAt(chunk.length - 1) != quote)
                        {
                            line[i] += ',' + line[j];
                            line.splice(j, 1);
                            chunk = line[j].replace(/[\s]*$/g, "");
                        }

                        if (j < line.length)
                        {
                            line[i] += ',' + line[j];
                            line.splice(j, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
                {
                    // remove leading/trailing whitespace
                    line[i] = line[i].replace(/^[\s]*|[\s]*$/g, "");

                    // remove leading/trailing quotes
                    if (line[i].charAt(0) == '"') line[i] = line[i].replace(/^"|"$/g, "");
                    else if (line[i].charAt(0) == "'") line[i] = line[i].replace(/^'|'$/g, "");
                }

                return line;
            }

            function csvToJson ()
            {
                var message = "";
                var error = false;
                var f = document.forms["convertForm"];
                var csvText = f.elements["csv"].value;
                var jsonText = "";

                setMessage(message, error);

                if (csvText == "") { error = true; message = "Enter CSV text below."; }

                if (!error)
                {
                    benchmarkStart = new Date();
                    csvRows = csvText.split(/[\r\n]/g); // split into rows

                    // get rid of empty rows
                    for (var i = 0; i < csvRows.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (csvRows[i].replace(/^[\s]*|[\s]*$/g, '') == "")
                        {
                            csvRows.splice(i, 1);
                            i--;
                        }
                    }

                    if (csvRows.length < 2) { error = true; message = "The CSV text MUST have a header row!"; }
                    else
                    {
                        objArr = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < csvRows.length; i++)
                        {
                            csvRows[i] = parseCSVLine(csvRows[i]);
                        }

                        benchmarkParseEnd = new Date();

                        for (var i = 1; i < csvRows.length; i++)
                        {
                            if (csvRows[i].length > 0) objArr.push({});

                            for (var j = 0; j < csvRows[i].length; j++)
                            {
                                objArr[i - 1][csvRows[0][j]] = csvRows[i][j];
                            }
                        }

                        benchmarkObjEnd = new Date();

                        jsonText = JSON.stringify(objArr, null, "\t");

                        benchmarkJsonEnd = new Date();

                        f.elements["json"].value = jsonText;

                        benchmarkPopulateEnd = new Date();

                        message = getBenchmarkResults();


                    }
                }

                setMessage(message, error);
            }

$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){

                console.log('i got here');
                csvToJson;


            });



});
```

This works perfectly but console.log is never shown.

And if I try to do something like return the jsonText from the csvToJson function and then append it to the second textarea, that doesn't work either.

```
function csvToJson ()

{

//same code here

return jsonText;

}


$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){

                console.log('i got here');
                jsont = csvToJson();
                                $("#json").val(jsonT);


            });
```

It's clearly something I don't get about submitting. Should I use jquery .submit() function ?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Second `csvToJson` has no arguments, so really not sure what it does without seeing more of it's code. It appears you have a scope problem and are likely throwing errors

Comment: The thing is that it work on localhost. This is the link http://jsfiddle.net/MRmJM/
It doesn't work though in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets when calling `csvToJson` inside the click handler.

Change:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){ 
                csvToJson;
});
```

TO

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){ 
                csvToJson();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MRmJM/1/

One note: If CSV is separated by semi-colon (not uncommon) , parser code fails to create proper object

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why doesn't console.log message appear ? Whatt happend is I change the value of the second textarea through jquery and not javascript ? That doesn't work for me

Comment: it appears for me..what browser are you using?

Comment: this is strange, it work for me to in js fiddle. not working in chrome, not working in firefox either.

Comment: is it necessary to convert csv in client? Why not convert at server? Most server languages have csv libraries. Also is working for me in Chrome,FF and IE9. Lower versions of IE will need library fallback support  for `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I work now, thanks a lot. I had to clean the history/cache of chrome.